# Question on trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Let $ABC$ be an acute-angle triangle with area $K$.

Show that:

\begin{equation} \sqrt{a^2b^2-4K^2}+ \sqrt{b^2c^2-4K^2} + \sqrt{c^2a^2-4K^2}=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}\end{equation}

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $K=\frac{ab\sin \gamma}{2}=\frac{bc \sin \alpha}{2}=\frac{ac \sin \beta}{2}$

Replace $K$ with the corresponding formula we get that

$\sqrt{a^2b^2-a^2b^2 \sin^2 \gamma} + \sqrt{b^2c^2-b^2c^2 \sin^2 \alpha} + \sqrt{a^2c^2-a^2c^2 \sin^2 \beta} $

$=ab\cos \gamma + bc \cos \alpha + ac \cos \beta$

Now we have to prove that

$a^2+b^2+c^2=2ab\cos \gamma + 2bc\cos \alpha + 2ac \cos \beta$

This follows immediately from cosine theorem .

Comment: Thanks for remembering $K=\frac{absinγ}{2}=\frac{bcsinα}{2}=\frac{acsinβ}{2}$. +1